# How to convert Linq query to a DataTable, DataSet or DataView?

Tags: .net, linq, datatable, dataset, dataview

Is there an easy way to do this or do I just need to go through each record and insert it into whatever data structure I go with?

I need it in this format in order to pass it to a third party software called Aspose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSets are about DataTables; DataTables and DataViews are about DataRows. Linq queries are about objects.

If you want to execute a Linq2SQL query or Linq2Entities query and put the result into a collection of DataRows you will have to manually convert each instance of your query result to a DataRow type (and define the various DataColumns...).

The trivial solution of you question is using a LINQ query towards a DataTable... it will return a set of DataRows... but I don't think this is the main point of you question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the DataSource property to the results of any Linq query.

Comment: I need this in order to pass it to a third party software called Aspose.

Comment: @Abe - what exactly do you need to pass to Aspose? A dataset, an IEnumerable, an IQueryable...

Comment: Any of the structures i mentioned in my post or IDataReder